# How to customize Aggregate.match(...) MongoDB For Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

I need to customize the aggregate match condition here the exemple (note: `filters` is the list for the all condition that I need to implement in `$match`):

```
 public static void filterQueryForSuppWarning(QueryParamDto queryParamDto, List<Bson> filters) {
        if (queryParamDto != null) {
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(queryParamDto.getUets())) {
                filters.add(eq(ID_UET.getLabel(),queryParamDto.getUets()));
            }
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(queryParamDto.getMgtgroups())) {
                filters.add(eq(PN_MANAGEMENT_GROUP.getLabel(), queryParamDto.getMgtgroups()));
            }
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(queryParamDto.getSuppliers())) {
                filters.add(eq(SupplierFieldEnum.SUP_NAME.getLabel(), queryParamDto.getSuppliers()));
            }
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(queryParamDto.getReference())) {
                filters.add(eq(ID_PN_PARTNUMBER.getLabel(), queryParamDto.getReference()));
            }
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(queryParamDto.getSupplierAddressCodes())) {
                filters.add(eq(SupplierFieldEnum.CODE_SUPPLIER_DLAP_SITE.getLabel(), queryParamDto.getSupplierAddressCodes()));
            }
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(queryParamDto.getSupplierAccounts())) {
                filters.add(eq(SupplierFieldEnum.ID_SUP_NUMBER.getLabel(), queryParamDto.getSupplierAccounts()));
            }
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(queryParamDto.getAppReference())) {
                filters.add(eq(APP_REFERENCE.getLabel(), queryParamDto.getAppReference()));
            }

            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(queryParamDto.getWarnings())) {
                for (String code : queryParamDto.getWarnings()) {
                    filters.add(eq(code.toLowerCase(),1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem for `aggregate.match` don't support `List<Bson>`.

How can I implement many condition like this example to my query:

```
AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
    Aggregates.match(and(eq("dt_extract","2017-07-03"), eq("id_pn_partnumber",queryParamDto.getReference()))),
    Aggregates.project(include("id_sup_number","sup_name",                                       "group_name","code_supplier_dlpa_site","idPnPartNumber"))
));
```

Comment: What you posted at the end of your question looks valid: `Aggregates.match(Filters.and(Filters.eq("dt_extract","2017-07-03"), Filters.eq("id_pn_partnumber",queryParamDto.getReference())))`. This creates an _and_ filter which encapsulates multiple _eq_ filters.

Comment: @glytching Yes is valid but i need to add the List of Bson(filters) to my condition for $match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Filters.and()` accepts an iterable (since v3.2, at least). From the [Javadoc](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/):

> **`public static Bson and(Iterable<Bson> filters)`**
>
> Creates a filter that performs a logical AND of the provided list of filters. Note that this will only generate a "$and" operator if absolutely necessary, as the query language implicity ands together all the keys.

So, the following code will work:

```
List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<>();

// populate filters, as per your filterQueryForSuppWarning() 
// ...

AggregateIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        // wrap your list of filters in an 'and' and assign that directly to the $match stage
        Aggregates.match(Filters.and(filters)),
        Aggregates.project(Projections.include("id_sup_number", "sup_name",
                "group_name", "code_supplier_dlpa_site", "idPnPartNumber"))
));
```